# Automatic delete date for posts in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, soft-delete

I want to use `softdelete()` method of Laravel in my app and I want to say soft-delete the post after 30 days of publishing date and time, currently I do not have any code in my app because I'm researching first to see if it's possible or not.

My question is how can I say that the post has to be delete in 30 days after publishing date?

Answer (score 2):

Create a job or command and perform the operation in there. Setup the task scheduler and schedule the task to run your job or command once a day or hour depending on your desired speed of post removal.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

You can also write the code directly in the scheduler if it's simple.

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    Post::where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->delete();
})->daily();
```

Be sure to enable soft deletes on your model.

Comment: so you say with this way i don't need to use cornjob right?

Comment: This in turn needs you to setup a cronjob for laravel task scheduler to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#introduction).

You'll need to manually add a single cronjob that actually triggers the scheduler in Laravel. After this you create a command that deletes those old posts.

This command gets scheduled to run how often you want and the scheduler will handle the every run of that scheduled command (see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#defining-schedules)).